# Use my own python libraries in visual studio code on raspberry pi

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I have a directory that contains sub directories of code that I reuse.

```
MyBaseDirectory

    \genericcodedir1

       reuse1.py

   \simpleapp1

      app1.py
```

app1.py has the following line

```
import reuse1
```

Visual studio will fail to run this since it says it can't find the library.

On windows I simply added the genericcodedir1 to the PYTHONPATH environment variable and all is well.

What should I do on the raspberry pi to allow this to run?

error message:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'reuse1'
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Mybasedirectory/simpleapp1/app1.py", line 5, in <module>
    import reuse1
```

Comment: can you provide the error text and a snippet of your files structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have file structure like this and you open **Test** folder in VS Code As follows.

[image]

You can specify the path by adding the following code above the import statement in **app.py**:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("./genericcodedir1")

import reuse1
```

In addition, you can add the following configuration to the **settings.json** file to make vscode recognize `reuse1`.

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./genericcodedir1"
    ]
}
```

*code and result*

[image]

Comment: So looks like VS code added the path to the settings.json automatically anyway - first bit of the problem seems to be solved by adding the following to launch.json

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "$PYTHONPATH:/home/pi/Desktop/reuse1" 
            }
        },
<br>
Think I'm still going to need to figure something for the path variable when running outside of VSCode.

Comment: **launch.json** only works when debugging. You can use **Ctrl+Shift+P** to open the [command panel](https://imgur.com/a/dnz9a4X), then search for `settings` to open **settings.json**.

Answer (score 0):

so if your files looks like :

```
|_genericcodedir
  |_reuse1.py
|_simpleapp1
  |_app1.py
```

you need to add an empty file called `__init__.py` in your genericcodedir.

another note worthy thing is your working directory (the directory in which your terminal runs)
you may need to append to os path depending on where you are when launching the program

Comment: it just tells python that the directory is a module. i can't find a link on it unfortunately

Comment: Sorry - adding the init.py didn't work - I ran on the PC rather than the raspberry pi - how do I add to the path on raspberry pi - bearing in mind I'm trying to debug from visual studio.

Comment: can you run ```pwd``` and ```ls -R``` in raspberry pi terminal?